# Flutter Chrome Custom Tabs, Store and retrieve data

Tags: flutter, chrome-custom-tabs

Is it possible to store and retrieve data in custom tab flutter.
Or Any ways by which we can send data from custom tab to the flutter application ?

For example -  Application A uses Chrome tab to login into some website, on success it gets back the token.Now if Application B open the chrome tab with same website, it will by default logged in(as chrome custom tab shares the session) . But now it wants that token which was received by Application A, can that token be stored in custom tabs ? and can Application B retrieve that from custom tabs ?

Regards